# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel with php5.6 installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

any help is appreciated :

**the database have the tables created and working fine  : **

but the browser returns error (Trying to get property of non-object (View: )

**The controller file is  :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\DocTracking;
use App\Models\User;
use Exception;
use Auth;
use PDF;
use QrCode;
use Carbon;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\input;


class DocTrackingController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['only', 'getDashboard']);
    }
  public function index(Request $request,$id=null)
    {
        if(!Auth::check()){
            return "Please Login";
        }
        if($id != null){
            $userid= $id;
        }
        else {
            $user_id= Auth::user()->id;
            $selluser = User::find($user_id);
        }

       $data = DocTracking::all();
        $data = array(
    'name'=> $request->name,
            'start_date'  =>Carbon::parse( $request->start_date),
            'end_date' =>Carbon::parse( $request->end_date),
            'amount' => $request->amount,
            'merchant_id'=> $user_id
  );
/*
  $doc_data  =  DocTracking::all();
        $doc_data = response()->json($data);
        $doc_data = json_encode($data);

       return view('doctracking.doctracking' ,['selluser'=>$selluser, 'doc_data' => $doc_data]);  // return view('doctracking.doctracking',compact('doctracking') );


    }
  public function add_doc(Request $request)
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name'=> 'required',
            'start_date'=> 'required',
            'end_date'=> 'required',
            'amount'=> 'required',
            'select_file'=> 'required |image |mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg |max:2048',
        ]);


        $this->validate( $request, [
            'name'=> 'required',
            'start_date'=> 'required',
            'end_date'=> 'required',
            'amount'=> 'required',
            'select_file'=> 'required |image |mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg |max:2048',
        ]);

         if ( $validation->passes())
         {

            $user_id= Auth::user()->id;

             $image = time().'.'.$request->file('select_file')->getClientOrignalExtension();
             $request->file('select_file')->move(public_path('images'), $image);

            $file=$request->file('select_file');
            $uploaded_file_path='';
            if($file!=null) {
                $destinationPath = 'images/docktracking/';
                $uploaded=$file->move($destinationPath,$file->getClientOriginalName());
                $image= $uploaded->getPathName();
                $img_name= $file->getClientOriginalName();
            }
            $data = array(
                'name'=> $request->name,
                'start_date'  =>Carbon::parse( $request->start_date),
                'end_date' =>Carbon::parse( $request->end_date),
                'amount' => $request->amount,
                'merchant_id'=> $user_id,
                'image' =>$img_name

            );

            $doc_data= DocTracking::create($data);
            return response()->json($doc_data);

    }
}
}

?>
```

**The model file is :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DocTracking extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'doctracking';
}
?>
```

> **the view file is :**

```
@foreach ( (array)$doc_data as $data )
          {{  $data->id }}
@endforeach
```

i think that if   {{$data->id}}    get the data then every thing will work fine

Comment: Try `$data['id']`

Comment: now this error             Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: Remove these two lines `$doc_data = response()->json($data);
        $doc_data = json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `'id'` key to your data array (of course return the array as `'doc_data'` like you do right now):

```
$data = array(
    'id' => $id
    'name' => $request->name,
    'start_date' => Carbon::parse( $request->start_date),
    'end_date' => Carbon::parse( $request->end_date),
    'amount' => $request->amount,
    'merchant_id' => $user_id
);

return view('doctracking.doctracking', [
     'selluser' => $selluser, 
     'doc_data' => $data
]);
```

Access it like this:

```
@foreach($doc_data as $data)
      {{ $data['id'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Make sure `$id` contains a value.

Comment: same  issue  Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: do you mean like     $data = DocTracking::all();

Comment: I don't know, depends on what you want to show. In your question you are assigning values to $data twice.

Comment: i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

You should return a view in your index function with the parameter you want to pass.

```
$doc_data = DocTracking::all();
return view('doctracking.doctracking',compact('doc_data') );
```

and in view

```
@foreach($doc_data as $data)
  {{ $data->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: now the two files are talking to each other    but still have this error             Undefined variable: doc_data

Comment: the name of the variable must be the same on 1: the declaration of the variable, 2: on the compact function inside the return view, and 3: in your view, check that you have the same name in these 3 places

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that from your Controller, you are returning a `$doc_data` object because in your current code, the return statement is commented out so I don't know what's with that.

Second, inside your view, you are having code:

```
@foreach ( (array)$doc_data as $data )
          {{  $data->id }}
@endforeach
```

You are basically type casting `$doc_data` into an array yourself and then trying to access it as an object :) of course you are getting `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

Either use it as object:

```
@foreach ( $doc_data as $data )
          {{  $data->id }}
@endforeach
```

OR use it as array:

```
@foreach ( (array)$doc_data as $data )
          {{  $data['id'] }}
@endforeach
```

Can't have it both ways :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$data` variable to fetch `DocTracking` data,

further you are overwriting `$data` with array which does not contain `id`

also you can convert result in array using toArray() function

`$data = DocTracking::get()->toArray();`